# gcc using -I include/ -L lib/ commands when the files are in the same folder?

Tags: windows, gcc, compilation, raylib

Given a folder 'ex' with the files below where I open a windows cmd console in ex...

```
ex\input.c  
ex\lib_folder\librarylib.a  
ex\include_folder\raylib.h
```

How do I change the below command to work if the second and third files are sitting beside input.c instead of in their own folders? i.e. ex\librarylib.a; ex\raylib.h

```
gcc in.c -I include_folder/ -L lib_folder/ -lraylib -lopengl32 -lwinmm -o out.exe
```

If I put the entire path name after -I it just says cannot find directory or that's not a directory. Or it goes to the first library -lraylib and doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a single dot as folder name to specify the current folder. So use `-I.` and `-L.`